# Getting field value counts and pushing values to other field of other model

Tags: python, django

I have following two models:

```
class New(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    publish = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Crawler(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    total_news_crawled= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(True)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to do something like

```
total_news_crawled = (select count(source) from New where source = 'xyz')
```

and store in `total_news_crawled` of Crawler model. How can that be done?

Comment: What do u mean with available? Non empty strings?

Comment: @Ianzz sorry. That was mistake. Thank you for your concern..

Comment: I mean run some queries to sources field, may be counting the number of some specific strings. Do you get me?

Comment: some thing like: `n = New.objects.filter( source = 'pepe' ).count()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way:

```
#counting
n = New.objects.filter( source = 'xyz' ).count()

#storing
c = Crawler.objects.get( id = **some id**)
c.total_news_crawled = n
c.save()
```

Don't forget import models.

**Edited due OP comment**

You can write a custom method to update your field:

```
class Crawler(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    total_news_crawled= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(True)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def update_total_news_crawled( self ):
        self.total_news_crawled = New.objects.filter( source = 'xyz' ).count()
```

**Edited due OP comment**

To call custom method:

```
c = Crawler()
c.name = "crazy crawler"
c.Id = "abc"
c.active = True
c.update_total_news_crawled()
c.save()
```

Comment: Where should i do this?

Comment: i was expecting to do this in models.py. Is that possible??

Comment: Of course. You can overwrite save method or create a custom method to update it.

Comment: By the way, how does the update_total_news_crawled() get called??